# ¿Cómo se guarda y escribe un archivo con la función File()?

Tags: javascript, html5

Recientemente he estado intentando guardar un archivo o escribirlo, pero he sido incapaz. Aquí he el código que he intentado:

```
<script>
file=new File(new Blob(["Normal Text."],{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"}),"hello world.txt")
</script>
```

Y el error:

> Failed to construct 'File': The 1st argument is neither an array, nor does it have indexed properties.(…)

Es curioso que me rechaze algo que se supone que funciona en los otros navegadores, más los míos ni si quiera me piden actualizaciones. ¿Qué hago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en el orden de los parámetros. En la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File#Implementation_notes) puedes ver que la estructura sería:

```
new File(
  Array parts,
  String filename, 
  BlobPropertyBag properties
);
```

pero tu código tiene primero un blob y luego el nombre del fichero. No sólo el número de parámetros es incorrecto, sino que tampoco están en el orden correcto. Arregla eso e inténtalo de nuevo.

---

Parece que lo que quieres es guardar el fichero en disco directamente. Si no me equivoco, eso no se puede hacer con la API File. Con ella puedes crear ficheros al vuelo o leer ficheros, pero no guardarlos directamente en el ordenador del usuario (por seguridad).

Para guardarlos lo que puedes hacer es crear un enlace al contenido del fichero que has creado. Para ello podrías hacer algo como [koldev sugiere en este JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/). La idea es leer el fichero que se ha creado como un Blob y hacer un enlace al mismo.

El código, con algunas modificaciones para simplificarlo y que no se descargue automáticamente podría ser algo así:

```js
// creas el fichero con la API File
var file = new File(["Normal Text."],"hello world.txt",{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});

// obtienes una URL para el fichero que acabas de crear
var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

// creas un enlace y lo añades al documento
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);

// actualizas los parámetros del enlace para descargar el fichero creado
a.href = url;
a.innerHTML = "Descargar fichero";
a.download = file.name;
```

---

O si quieres que se descargue directamente usa el mismo código del JSFiddle de koldev sólo cambiando el fichero para que se ajuste al tuyo (también lo he simplificado un poco):

```js
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function () {
        var blob = new File(["HOLA Mundo!"], "holamundo.txt");
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = blob.name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

saveData();
```

Comment: new File(["Normal Text."],"hello world.txt",{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
Así estaría correcto, al parecer.

Comment: Funciona aun en 2024 con toda la paranoya de seguridad actual de los navegadores. Mil gracias

Answer (score 2):

Un ejemplo correcto del uso **API [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File)** seria:

```
new File(["Normal Text."],"hello world.txt",{type:"text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
```

> Debido a que lo que quieres es escribir en el **filesystem** el
>   archivo creado, podemos contemplar usar la **API FileSystem**

Para ello, necesitas realizar los siguientes pasos:

> **IMPORANTE: Google Chrome cuenta con la única implementación operativa del API de FileSystem.**

- **Primero**: Solicita permiso al navegador

  ```
  function errorHandler () {
    /** codigo **/
  }
  function onInitFs(fs) {
     /** Codigo **/
  }

  //
  navigator.persistentStorage = window.persistentStorage || navigator.webkitPersistentStorage;
  window.requestFileSystem= window.requestFileSystem|| window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

  //
  navigator.persistentStorage.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, 1024*1024, function(grantedBytes) {

    // Tras recibir permisos para almacenar archivos
    // debes solicitar un punto al fileSystem
    window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
  }, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
  });
  ```
- **Segundo**: Crea un archivo el el filesystem

  ```
  function onInitFs(fs) {

    // Creamos el archivo el el filesystem
    fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {

      // fileEntry.isFile === true
      // fileEntry.name == 'log.txt'
      // fileEntry.fullPath == '/log.txt'

    }, errorHandler);
  }
  ```
- **Tercero**: Escribe en el archivo

  ```
  function onInitFs(fs) {

    // Creamos el archivo el el filesystem
    fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

      // fileEntry es el puntero a archivo log.txt.
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
          console.log('Escritura completada!.');
        };

        fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
          console.log('Escritura fallida: ' + e.toString());
        };

        // Creamos un Bolb y lo escribimos en log.txt.
        var blob = new Blob(['Hola mundo!'], {type: 'text/plain'});
        fileWriter.write(blob);
      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
  }
  ```

**Aquí, el código completo**:

```
function errorHandler() {
  console.log('Error!', arguments);
}

function onInitFs(fs) {

  // Creamos el archivo el el filesystem
  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', { create: true }, function(fileEntry) {

    // fileEntry es el puntero a archivo log.txt.
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
          console.log('Escritura completada!.');
      };

      fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
          console.log('Escritura fallida: ' + e.toString());
      };

      // Creamos un Bolb y lo escribimos en log.txt.
      var blob = new Blob(['Hola mundo!'], { type: 'text/plain' });
      fileWriter.write(blob);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
}

//
navigator.persistentStorage = window.persistentStorage || navigator.webkitPersistentStorage;
window.requestFileSystem= window.requestFileSystem|| window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

navigator.persistentStorage.requestQuota(1024 * 1024, function(grantedBytes) {

  // Tras recibir permisos para almacenar archivos
  // debes solicitar un punto al fileSystem
  window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, onInitFs, errorHandler);
}, function(e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
});
```

Link a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Socramg/e6m5zL5g/1/

eBook: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/using-the-html5/9781449311384/

Mas info: https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Librería recomendada: https://github.com/summera/chromestore.js/

Comment: Es curioso, no veo que aparezca el archivo por ninguna parte.

Comment: Eso es solo para crearlo. Quieres descargarlo o subirlo a un servidor?

Comment: Efectivamente, si es para crearlo, no apareció en la carpeta donde ejecuté el html, aunque tampoco dió error...

Comment: Estoy trabajando en Windows 10 internamente.

Comment: Estoy ejecutándolo con chrome. Con firefox pasa lo mismo: No guarda y no da error...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47468/discussion-between-marcos-gallardo-and-tato-broh).

Comment: chat1253123412.htm:29 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.(anonymous function) @ chat1253123412.htm:29
chat1253123412.htm:35 Error DOMError

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Por otro lado, si la idea realmente es hacer un chat, yo te sugiero que uses websokets.

Comment: Intenta aportar información a mi nueva pregunta:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30853/c%c3%b3mo-guardo-y-leo-en-php-con-el-fin-de-hacer-un-chat/30854?noredirect=1#comment50282_30854

Comment: No se me crea ningún archivo log.txt, sin embargo me dice "Escritura completada!".

Comment: Esto es lo que dice la documentación: *"La API no le da acceso al sistema de archivos local, ni tampoco el sandbox es realmente una sección del sistema de archivos. En su lugar, es un sistema de archivos virtualizado que parece un sistema de archivos completo para la aplicación web. No tiene necesariamente una relación con el sistema de archivos local fuera del navegador"*, mas info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction

Comment: ¿Confías en que javascript de Chrome y Firefox no puede crear archivos?

Comment: Con la API de FileSystem se pueden crear archivos, pero no en *"C:\"*. Estos archivos se crean en un sistema virtualizado que provee el browser. Te recomiendo leer este libro: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/using-the-html5/9781449311384/

Comment: Con tu código los archivos no se generan tanto en un dominio como en C:\
Con respecto a tu libro necesito uno de chrome, no de safari.