# ¿Cómo guardo y leo en php con el fin de hacer un chat?

Tags: php, html5

Mis bienes son especiales con solemnidad. Aquí tienen mi código en html:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myfile=fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!")
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"))
fclose($myfile)
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Y aquí lo que me aparece en la página:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/u447364596/public_html/no funciona.php on line 7
```

Intenté probar también la escritura:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<body>

<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo no me deja escoger el contenido del archivo.

---

Actualización.

---

Nuevo código:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>body{background-color:black;color:white}</style>
<script>
<?
$myfile=fopen("chat10.txt","r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$writed=fread($myfile,filesize("chat10.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
$myfile=fopen("chat10.txt","w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,$writed."An user has connected. <br>");
fclose($myfile);
?>
setInterval(function(){
document.body.innerHTML="<?
$myfile=fopen("chat10.txt","r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("chat10.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>"
},1)
onkeydown=function(){}
</script>
```

Y el error es que cuando pongo un evento de escritura a la función "onkeydown", no se me escriben las cosas cuando presiono una tecla, sino cuando entro en html, y deja de escribirse lo que inicialmente puse.

Me gustaría poder hacer un archivo php que mandase un mensaje de entrada personalizado por el usuario a un archivo.htm, y que al entrar se actualizase todo el rato, mostrando así toda la información que se ha enviado al htm, y que al presionar cierta tecla se vuelva a enviar un mensaje al archivo htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como complemento a la respuesta de Javier Paz Sedano puedo poner el siguiente código, esta parte lee los mensajes:

```
<script>
document.write("Chat started. <br>")
setInterval(function(){
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
document.body.innerHTML=this.responseText;
}}
xhr.open("GET","mensajes.txt",true);
xhr.send()
},500)
</script>
```

Y esta parte los escribe:

```
<?
$myfile=fopen("mensajes.txt","w")
fwrite($myfile,"Nuevo mensaje.<br>")
fclose($myfile)
?>
```

Comment: ¿Hay solución a esta pregunta?

Comment: Ese es el chat, no?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, los PHP sólo responden cuando el usuario ha mandado una petición. Si quieres que se "actualice todo el rato", sin que el usuario tenga que pulsar nada, tienes que meter un código JavaScript que mande peticiones al servidor todo el rato para ver si hay algo nuevo. Por ejemplo, mediante AJAX:

```
var getMessages = function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "contenidos_chat.php", true);
  xhttp.send()
}

setInterval(getMessages, 500)
```

Esto actualiza un div (o la etiqueta que sea) con id="chat" con el contenido del chat cada 500 milisegundos. Puedes cambiar la frecuencia cambiando el parámetro de setInterval.

Lo segundo, no deberías usar ficheros planos para guardar la conversación, no es thread safe, y en cuanto aumente el número de usuarios van a empezar a pasar cosas raras, como que dos escriban a la vez y sus frases se "mezclen". Utilizando una base de datos te ahorarrías esos problemas. Las bases de datos llevan protección contra escrituras concurrentes incorporada.

Y en cuanto al tema ficheros. Claro que se puede crear un archivo y al tanto guardarlo. Basta abrirlo con la bandera "w" (modo escritura). Te da error al abrir "webdictionary.txt" porque lo estás abriendo en modo lectura (bandera "r") y para poder hacer eso tienes que haberlo creado antes. Si no, no hay datos que leer. Ojo que si abres un fichero con "w" te lo crea vacío y te machaca lo que hubiera antes.

Comment: El problema con ese código que pusistes es que no hay forma de escribir en él. Te dejo otra pregunta mía para que lo aclares allí:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29421/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-chat-con-xmlhttprequest?noredirect=1#comment47506_29421

Comment: Puedes mandar parámetros GET. Por ejemplo, la URL puede ser 'escribir_chat.php?mensaje="Hola paco"'. Desde el PHP sólo tendrías que leer $_GET["mensaje"] y tendrías el mensaje para escribirlo.

Comment: Recuerda escribir en la pregunta que trata sobre tu respuesta:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29421/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-chat-con-xmlhttprequest?noredirect=1#comment47506_29421
Otro punto. El código que pusistes está en javascript, no puedes ejecutar un archivo php con javascript, o mezclarlo, sería demasiado lioso y/o daría errores.

Comment: También ten en cuenta que pretendo mandar mensajes por teclado...

Comment: Cualquier página web es una arquitectura cliente-servidor, y en dichas arquitecturas siempre hay código de cliente (javascript) y código de servidor (PHP). Es la manera estandar de hacer las cosas, cada uno se ejecuta en un sitio diferente y no da errores por el mero hecho de usar los dos lenguajes. De hecho, es la única manera de hacer una interfaz no estática.

Comment: En cuanto a lo de mandar mensajes por teclado, no lo mencioné porque pensaba que sabías cómo van los formularios. Sería añadir un <form action="grabar_mensaje.php"> con un <input type="text" name="mensaje"> y un <button type="submit">. Al darle a enviar, el código grabar_mensaje.php tiene en el parámetro "mensaje" el contenido del input. Léete un tutorial de PHP porque creo que lo que necesitas es base de arquitectura web.

Comment: No, lo que necesito es hacer un chat en el cual se puedan enviar mensajes con solo presionar una tecla. ¿Es posible?

Comment: También sería de utilidad un código que al ejecutarse en un servicio php almacenara los mensajes en este con $_POST y los leyera con $_GET. Dudo que sea tan difícil ¿No? Concreta tu pregunta con esos detalles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myfile=fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!") // <-- Falta ;
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt")) // <-- Falta ;
fclose($myfile) // <-- Falta ;
?>
```

Prueba a poner ';' al finalizar las instrucciones :)

En cuanto a la escritura...

Yo empezaría por comprobar si `$myfile` es un descriptor válido:

```
if (false === $myfile)
{ /* Error al abrir el fichero */ }
```

También comprobaría el número de bytes escritos al usar `fwrite`.

```
if (fwrite($myfile, $txt) === FALSE)
{ /* Error al escribir en el fichero */ }
```

Y también miraría a ver si es un problema de privilegios de escritura. Esto lo haría antes de intentar abrir el fichero:

```
// Por no repetir el nombre cada dos por tres
$nombre_fichero = "webdictionary.txt";

if (!is_writable($nombre_fichero)) 
{ /* Sin privilegios de escritura */ }
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Muy bien, y ahora como escribo un archivo?

Comment: He editado la respuesta. A ver si te ayuda.

Comment: Nope, necesito que al entrar ponga un texto que eliga el usuario.

Comment: Entonces necesitas un formulario html y recibir los datos por `get` o `post` (este último recomendado) para hacer llegar al servidor los datos que introduzca el usuario. Sin embargo no has indicado ese detalle en la pregunta...

Comment: Necesito un formulario que se abra cuando presione una tecla, pero claro, php no es javascript, así que es prácticamente imposible que se guarde algo con solo presionar una tecla y escribir, supongo... ¿No?

Comment: deberías leerte un buen tutorial de PHP... php se ejecuta en el lado del servidor. Lo que tienes que hacer es programar un formulario en el lado cliente para que el navegador pueda enviar información a la capa PHP, ubicada en el servidor. Una vez el servidor tiene esa información puede hacer lo que quiera con ella (por ejemplo guardarla en un fichero). La capa cliente puede tener HTML, javascript y todo lo que te apetezca... son cosas independientes.

Comment: Exacto, entonces ¿Existe alguna manera de que php te pregunte por variables?

Comment: Esta es otra pregunta... o la pones de forma independiente o miras en Google sobre cómo crear formularios HTML y enlazarlos con PHP. Un saludo.

Comment: Imposible crearlos (Según google)...

Comment: Si fuese imposible no podrías iniciar sesión en Facebook o Gmail...

Comment: Ya te digo, según google, tal vez sea secreto de los judíos illuminati...

Comment: No son malos, pero a menudo ocultan cosas para que el tinglado no se les venga abajo y el demonio pueblo no entre a governar (Método el cual serviría como destrucción del mundo, viendo la cantidad enorme de trolls que  hay en este putrefacto planeta).

Comment: ¿No hay alguna manera de guardar las variables en una base de datos usando php como dice Javier? Estaría bueno.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer ejemplo te faltan los ; al final de cada sentencia:

```
$myfile=fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Warning: fopen(webdictionary.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u447364596/public_html/no funciona.php on line 6
Unable to open file!

Comment: Además ni sé cómo ejecutar un php de estos.

Comment: @TatoBroh Tendrías que indicar la ruta en la que está el fichero. En este caso te dice que no encuentra la ruta. ¿Está en la misma carpeta que el html?

Comment: Exacto, al menos puede cargar un archivo, el problema es como escribo en él.

Comment: O sea, estaría bien que se pudiese crear un archivo, y al tanto guardarlo.

Comment: @TatoBroh Para escribir en el puedes usar [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php). Para crear un fichero `fopen('webdictionary.txt', 'w');` y después usar el fwrite.

Comment: Quiero personalizar el mensaje, tenlo en cuenta, y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: También ten en cuenta que quiero se se actualize la información todo el rato, para que no queden fallas.

Comment: @TatoBroh Sinceramente, creo que para eso tendrías que crear una pregunta nueva, ya que has añadido un montón de cosas que no estaban en la pregunta original. De todas formas, dentro de un rato cuando tenga tiempo hago un edit y te intento ayudar.

Comment: Intenta ayudarme creando una sala de chat.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47752/discussion-between-error404-and-tato-broh).