# Como descargar XML del lado del Cliente obteniendo el documento por Response del Servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, xml

Estoy realizando una petición AJAX donde recibo una respuesta de tipo XML.

El Problema es que necesito descargar un archivo `.xml` con la respuesta que recibo del servidor.

Lo que he intentado es crear un `new File` con Javascript y luego descargar el archivo generado; esto es lo que tengo:

En el Controller:

```
$contenido = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><iva><TipoIDInformante>R</TipoIDInformante><IdInformante>1234555</IdInformante><razonSocial>ABCD EFGH</razonSocial><Anio>2019</Anio><Mes>01</Mes><compras>…</compras><ventas>…</ventas><ventasEstablecimiento>…</ventasEstablecimiento><exportaciones>…</exportaciones></iva>'
return response()->make($contenido, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Esta es la respuesta que obtengo del servidor:

```
<iva>
    <TipoIDInformante>R</TipoIDInformante>
    <IdInformante>1234555</IdInformante>
    <razonSocial>ABCD EFGH</razonSocial>
    <Anio>2019</Anio>
    <Mes>01</Mes>
    <compras>…</compras>
    <ventas>…</ventas>
    <ventasEstablecimiento>…</ventasEstablecimiento>
    <exportaciones>…</exportaciones>
</iva>
```

El envío AJAX se realiza pulsando un botón, esto funciona sin problemas

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('url') }}",
    data: {
        "mes": $('#mes').val(),
        "anno": $('#anno').val(),
        "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
        },
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "XML",
    success: function(xml) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        var blob = new File([xml], "AT"+$('#mes').val()+$('#anno').val()+".xml",  {type: "text/xml"});
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = blob.name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     },
     error: function () {}
});
</script>
```

Hasta aquí se genera un archivo que se envía a descargar cuando se ejecuta el **`success`**; pero cuando abro el archivo esto es lo que esta en su contenido

> [object XMLDocument]

Esto ultimo que he intentado fue basándome en esta pregunta
[¿Cómo se guarda y escribe un archivo con la función File()?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29933/c%C3%B3mo-se-guarda-y-escribe-un-archivo-con-la-funci%C3%B3n-file)

Comment: Comenta el `dataType: "XML",` y me dices si funciona.

Comment: No, sigue igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que se generaba es porque intentaba agregar el documento completo al archivo `file`, por eso al descargarlo su contenido era:

> [object XMLDocument]

La solución fue agregar esta linea de código `var xmlDoc = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);` que convierte a String el `XML` para luego poder agregarlo al archivo que se va a descargar.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url('url') }}",
    data: {
        "mes": $('#mes').val(),
        "anno": $('#anno').val(),
        "_token": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
        },
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "XML",
    success: function(xml) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display: none";

        //Serializo a String para poder agregar al archivo
        var xmlDoc = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xml);

        var blob = new File([xmlDoc], "AT"+$('#mes').val()+$('#anno').val()+".xml",  {type: "text/xml"});
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = blob.name;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
     },
     error: function () {}
});
</script>
```

Lo que necesitaba para obtener correctamente estaba aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/17671495/8451749